# Can CMake generate build scripts which do *not* use cmake?

Tags: c++, build-process, cmake

Question: Can CMake generate build scripts that do not, in any way, use CMake? If not, how hard is it to gut a CMake generated automake script to not make any checks against CMake?

I am a big fan of CMake to the point where I am championing the idea that we transition to it in my current work environment. One thing that could ease this transition from our current build system to CMake would be if I could demonstrate that CMake can generate automake files that do not require cmake themselves.

Clearly, I would never want to do this for day to day use, but having the ability to easily create a branch of our code that can be built from source without requiring cmake would go a long way in helping me make my case.

Comment: I find it odd that the answers here are "no". I'm just getting to the point with cmake that I'm starting to understand how to use it (rather than trying to force it to do something it's not designed for), such as using out-of-source builds etc. But I do know that cmake is bundled with cpack, which can generate tarballs on Linux and similar. If a tarball requires cmake to build, I'm not convinced it's a tarball at all.

Comment: I will take a closer look at CPack ;)

Comment: The tarballs generated by CPack are typically not source tarballs for building, but rather binary tarballs for running the system.

Comment: It's ironic that you would refer to a "CMake generated automake script".  Automake is one of the tools that CMake replaces, but the word 'automake' is clearly ingrained in the culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, CMake cannot do this. It doesn't really make sense, either, since without any CMake-support at build-time, there would be no way to check or update the makefiles/project-files themselves when the CMakeLists.txt files have changed.

If you are moving from Visual Studio to CMake, you may want to take a look at [vcproj2cmake](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcproj2cmake/).

Comment: That is actually a "desired" consequence - I am interested in generating an auto tools "ready to distribute" kind of build, where make could be used to build the project without cmake dependencies of any kind - at that point, it is ok if changes are not reflected back in CMake.

Comment: That is a use case which CMake does not address.

Answer (score 6):

The ability to do this depends on your OS, I'm presuming Unix/Makefile or Windows/MSVC. If you're using MSVC, the cmake dependency should be eliminated by declaring the `CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION` option at the start of your cmake script.

```
SET(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION TRUE)
```

On Unix-based systems, however, the Makefiles are [tied](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-June/037257.html) explicitly to the cmake build files (CMakeFiles, etc). I suspect that this dependency could be bypassed by the strategic commenting out of Makefile directives although, I cannot say what they might be.

Comment: `CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION` supports the Ninja and Makefile generators as of [CMake 3.12](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/release/3.12.html#id6).

Answer (score 3):

CMake generated files depend on cmake for various commands such as create / remove / etc... not just to regenerate the makefiles on a change so removing cmake is not going to work.

Comment: +1 CMake can also be used as a scripting language (see option "-P" in the CMake manpage), and many projects use CMake as a replacement for shell scripts, for stuff like copying files around or invoking helper programs. These projects will require CMake at build time, not just for generating the makefile.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who has taken a large complex piece of software and recently pulled out its existing build system, installing a new build system in its place. I can tell you that it's not easy, but I would definitely not want shell scripts as part of my build process, if they can be avoided. More and more systems will find themselves with CMake on them anyway, as more big name software packages like LLVM and KDE start using it—This is an area where it really accels, large projects.

One of the nice things about CMake is it builds things quicker. Resorting to have to fork shell instances to interpret a script really slows down the build process.

Answer (score -1):

What about the 'atomic solution' ?

EX- auto-generate a "QT moc" file from CMakeLists.txt,  then build project that depends on the .cpp file being generated

```
# inside project level CMakeLists.txt 
# run shell script to create the "moc_GUICreator.cpp" auto-generated source file
if(UNIX)
execute_process(COMMAND "sh" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/generate_moc.sh  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts )
endif(UNIX)
```

Where the .sh file contains:

```
# generate_moc.sh
echo "generating moc file:  moc ../include/GUICreator.h  -o  ../src/moc_GUICreator.cpp "
moc ../include/GUICreator.h -o ../src/moc_GUICreator.cpp
```

Equivalent windows batch file, "moc_creator_win.bat":

```
moc "GUICreator.h" -o "moc_GUICreator.cpp"
```

Haven't tried this last bit in windows, but it or something very close should work, just after the if(UNIX) block in CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(WIN32)
execute_process(COMMAND "cmd" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/moc_creator_win.bat  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts )
endif(WIN32)
```

So, basically if you're clever you can do whatever you want from a script and use CMake variables as args to it, I'm not sure if you can ask for more...

the point is to avoid 'non-portable build types' unless you really need to hack it into a specialized compiler, or don't feel like using QT Designer to place the widgets ;-)

Comment: The point you can use CMake as intended, or at the opposite end of the spectrum, just wrap it around arbitrary scripts. There's nothing to stop you from parsing the cmake variables and generating whatever makefiles you desire...