# Generating redistributable Visual Studio project with cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

is it possible to generate Visual Studio projects that are redistributable with CMake?

The project file in question are examples/demos of our library. We don't want that our customers have to install cmake (and learn what to do with it) just to compile a few examples.

The problem with CMake generated project files is that they contain absolute paths (relativeliy easy to fix with string replacement) and references to CMake files (e.g. in prelin step. This is not easy to automatically change).

Does CMake provide an easy way to solve this problem?

Thank in advance

Comment: Regarding reference to cmake in generated build scripts see [Can CMake generate build scripts which do *not* use cmake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216935/can-cmake-generate-build-scripts-which-do-not-use-cmake) It looks like cmake build scripts always depends on cmake itself :(

Answer (score -2):

Yes,

you can have a cMake project, and generate Visual project on windows, XCode or makefile for other plateforms.
You use it for development, and after use install package makers like iceberg on mac, or scripts based installers on linux, or other installer creator on PC.(inno setup I think could be a solution)

Good luck

Comment: This does not answer the asked question.